# How to limit login for an Exchange server hosting multiple domains?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

this is my first question here, I usually read answers.

Today i'm asking this because I couldn't find what I'm looking for.

So I've my exchange server used for different authoritative domains,
I've 2 addresses to open OWA https:// domain1/owa and https:// domain2/owa, both works fine, my issue is that users with @domain1 and @domain2 can both login from either one or the other OWA addresses.

What I want to know is if there's a way that user@domain1 would login only with https:// domain1/owa and user@domain2 would login only with https:// domain2/owa, even though it's the same server?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: The domains aren't separate entities from the perspective of the Exchange server. The users aren't logging into "another domain". They're logging into their mailbox on the Exchange server. It doesn't matter what URL they use to get there. They could very well log in via the ip address (ignoring the certificate warning they would get when doing so). What's your real concern here?

Comment: To build on Joe's comment. Is the concern simply for aesthetics, user training, because of an internal policy or some other reason? I ask because the answer might depend on how much work you are willing to put forth to do it. For example, you could configure your firewall to deny incoming traffic to a certain URL based on source IP or login information (if you have DPI capabilities).

Answer (score 0):

No. 
The URL is just an address, it has no connection to the authoritative domain, email domain or anything else. There is no connection between them. It is just an address to access the web site. 
Even if you were to split OWA on to different servers, you cannot restrict access, as it is still the same Exchange org.

The only way I can think of doing such a restriction is to have the users in groups and then something publishing the URLs which limits the access (ISA, TMG type functionality). It isn't something that Exchange can do.

Why do you need to split the users up in that way? What I usually do is have a generic URL for users to use, so that the URL does not "belong" to a specific group of users.

Simon.

Comment: No. The URL is just an address, it has no connection to the authoritative domain, email domain or anything else. There is no connection between them. It is just an address to access the web site." 

I already knew this but I thought there was maybe a setting I could use like I do with some other (not Microsoft application).

it needs to be transparent. I need that just because, no reason, just want to do it. The check shouldn't be on the exchange server but before, on domain1 owa anything that isn't @domain1 you should be rejected.

Maybe if I duplicate the owa site and modify its content?

Comment: There is no mechanism within Exchange to limit the users. You can duplicate the web site, that works fine, but you cannot restrict the use of the site to certain users. If there is no reason to do so, I wonder what the point is? You are just making work for yourself for no gain. if you modify the web pages for OWA then you will loose those modifications when you update Exchange.